# AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_Cog'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i was trying to make a music bot in discord.py but i cant solve this one error

"AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_Cog'"

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class musik(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def join(self, ctx):
      if  ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send('get in a vc to use this')
      voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.voice_channel
      if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
      else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()  

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self, ctx, url):  
      ctx.voice_client.stop()
      FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect streamed 1-reconnect_delay max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
      YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
      vc = ctx.voice_client

      with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)

  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send('Paused.')

  @commands.command()
  async def resume(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send('Resumed.')        

def setup(client):
  client.add_Cog(music(client))
```

I am using replit to run the code if that makes any difference.
thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

`Bot.add_cog()` is the right method (c is lowercase).